# Specific 30x redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I do a 30x redirect in htaccess but only for URLs that start with this:

```
http://example.com/x/*
```

I want to redirect these to (HTTPS):

```
https://example.com/x/*
```

- as in wildcard, such as: example.com/x/batman

I don't want the redirect to affect any other URLs on this domain.

I can do this redirect with PHP, but my understanding is that if I do it in my `.htaccess` file, it will be a tiny bit faster as PHP won't have to be executed. Is that correct? Basically, I'm trying to do the fastest direct possible.

This is what I have so far, but its not much at all. It does work, and it redirects https to http successfully, but i need it to be only for specific urls, that follow the above described pattern:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you have just 1 domain? Is the `www` subdomain accessible? I assume `anything_here` is not actually part of the "URL that starts with..." as your question implies? So, the URL-path simply starts with `/x/`? Have you tried anything? This looks like a standard HTTP to HTTPS redirect - did you get an error or incorrect redirect when trying to implement this? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
> RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

To match a specific URL-path that starts `/x/` then change the `RewriteRule` to read `^x/` (no slash prefix) instead. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^x/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. (For this reason, it is easier to first test with temporary 302 redirects.)

However, a couple of notes regarding your directives...

- This is obviously redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP - the opposite of what you stated in your earlier example (and very much not recommended in 2019)?!
- The use of the `HTTPS` *environment variable* (ie. `%{ENV:HTTPS}`) is non-standard. Presumably this is under instruction from your host?

---

> `https://example.com/?wildcard` to be redirected to `http://example.com/wildcard`

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (eg. `^x/` above) matches against the URL-path only - which notably excludes the query string part of the URL.

To match the query string, you need a `RewriteCond` (*condition*) directive that matches against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example, to redirect `example.com/?foo` to `example.com/foo`, you would do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(foo)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1 [QSD,R,L]
```

Where `%1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the last matched condition. Note, there is no URL-path in the above example (denoted by the regex `^$`). The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag is reqd to remove the query string from the redirected URL.

If you wanted a more "wildcard" variation (that matches *anything* in the query string), as you appear to suggest in your example, then something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1 [QSD,R,L]
```

Note that a `R` flag without a status code defaults to a 302 (temporary) redirect.

Comment: yes, https->http, im playing around with scrubbing referrer and testing different techniques. Regarding the env. variable, it was the one that worked on my host out of those i tried. which one is standard, and i should use/get to work? also, your solution works!

Comment: would it be possible, with this solution to replace /x/ with any url that has query string. ex: https ://domain.tld/?wildcard to be redirected to http ://domain.tld/wildcard

Comment: If `ENV:HTTPS` is working for you then that is the one to use. This implies your host is using some kind of front-end proxy/load balancer to manage the SSL/TLS connection. Whilst `ENV:HTTPS` is "non-standard", it does seem to be reasonably common. The "standard one" would be the `HTTPS` _server variable_ (in contrast to the _env variable_), accessed via `%{HTTPS}`. But if there is a front-end proxy that manages SSL then that will not work.

Comment: "replace /x/ with any url that has query string" - Not quite. The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the URL-path only - this does not include the query string. To match the query string you need a `RewriteCond` directive that matches the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. "`https://example.com/?wildcard` to be redirected to `http://example.com/wildcard`" - that's really a different question, but I'll add an example to my answer....

Comment: i believe my host is using nginx infront of my apache vps, so thats probably why the ENV:HTTPS works. I have marked question as answered, thanks for your detail explanations.